# How to greyout a Fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, interface, android-viewpager, fragment

My application have a viewpager with the following fragment

1 Login 2 Measure 3 View Data

After the user login and swipe to the measure fragment my app will automatically measure some parameters.

As the viewpager is swipe-able . Is is possible to greyout/disable a fragment in the case where the user want to measure without login.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qt_deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qt_testtype"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qt_saveButton"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qt_saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/qt_deleteButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maintxt_measure"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/main_unknown" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have edit my layout file to the above however the layer below is still clickable. Is there any thing i missed ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, logically, on the layout of Measure and View Data, you can have a FrameLayout with 2 layers, one which contains everything you had, and one on top which is a layer of grey color imageview covering whole screen, so if user is not login, this imageview will be displayed, if user had login, you will set its visibility to gone. With this imageview on top, the other view elements will not receive any touching event.

Comment: Hi WaiChun , As per your suggestion i have updated my xml file . however the button below are still clickable . Thanks

Comment: Do this on your imageview, implement an onClickListner which will call a function that does absolutely nothing, then it will prevent  the bottom layer being accessible

Comment: You can refer to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but no, this is how it should probably look like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- You may change this to your relative layout, just make sure it is fill_parent -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Everything related to your main activity goes here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/faderLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#E0000000"
            android:onClick="faderClicked" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

So, in your activity, you will have a function `public void faderClicked(View v)` where it does nothing at all, and you control the view by changing faderLayout's visibility.